# Update infomation every time

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an android app where I can use my pc to update info on a app. For example (I have an app that can tell scores after every match for users to see) so how do I update info from my pc in order for the info on the app to keep changing. Its not a must for me to update the info using a pc but I want the user using an app to receive scores after every match.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a push notification system. [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) could be a good (free) starting point.

Another options:

- [Urban airship](https://go.urbanairship.com/)
- [Parse](https://parse.com/)